# css Checkbox Label Selector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, css, css-selectors

I'm developing a MVC3 application and need to select the `checkboxes` label.

In ASP MVC3 you have helper methods which creat a part of the code. So the code for a `checkbox` looks like this:

```
<input id="Jumping_successleicht" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Jumping_successleicht">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Jumping_successleicht">
<label for="Jumping_successleicht">
<span>leicht (4)</span>
</label>
```

Now I've thought I can use following code to select the `label`:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: url("../../Images/Controls/Checkbox.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    clear: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;
}
```

But it does not work. It looks like `label` and `input` have to be next to each other.

Does any ony have a solution how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no CSS selector that can be used to select the target of a `<label for="#">` element universally. The `+` selector is the "adjacent sibling" selector.

There are a few workarounds:

- Put the `<input>` element directly within the `<label>` element (you won't need the `for=""` attribute, that way).
- Seeing as each `<input />` needs to have a unique `id=""` attribute set in order to use `<label for="">`, just select the checkboxes by their IDs in the stylesheet.
- Assign classes for each of the appropriate inputs.
- Create wrappers around each input and its label.

Comment: A reference combinator has been proposed in the next spec that serves this specific purpose, but it looks like there hasn't been a decision whether to include it or not: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#idref-combinators Guess we'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this?

```
        input[type="checkbox"] + label{
            background-color:red;
        }
```